# Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined when setting Custom Dimension in Google Analytics tracking code

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, web-analytics

I am setting up a Custom Dimension in my Google Analytics Tracking Code, however I am seeing a strange error in the Chrome Console with the Google Analytics Debugger switched on.

This is my code which is fired on every page. I am reporting to a regional account as well as a global/rollup account and I have created two trackers to achieve this.

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-85521872-1', 'auto', 'crmpiccoglobal');
    ga('create', 'UA-85521872-3', 'auto', 'crmpiccoregion');

    ga('set', 'dimension1', 'premium');

    ga('crmpiccoglobal.send', 'pageview');
    ga('crmpiccoregion.send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

In the console I see this:

> Running command: ga("set", "dimension1", "premium")
>
> analytics_debug.js:10 Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined

I have created the Custom Dimension in GA under each property I want to access it in.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to use your tracker names in the "set" command, else GA will apply the command to the default tracker t0 (which does not exist in your example):

```
  ga('crmpiccoglobal.set', 'dimension1', 'premium');
  ga('crmpiccoregion.set', 'dimension1', 'premium');

  ga('crmpiccoglobal.send', 'pageview');
  ga('crmpiccoregion.send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: OFC, thanks. I was treating it like the `create` thinking I had to provide the tracker name at the end.

Comment: In my case, i use GTM to insert analytics. It sets the name as gtm1

Comment: @User, See the comment above yours, if you use Google Tag Manager, the `ga('create')` is run with the name gtm1 (in my case). So for example for event tracking i use `ga('gtm1.send' {....more data....} );` Use a Google analytics debug chrome extension, this helped me alot.

Answer (score 9):

If you use Google Tag Manager to load your Google Analytics and you don't know what tracker is being created, use this:

```js
sendGa(name : string, data: any) {
    (<any>window).ga(() => {
        const trackers = (<any>window).ga.getAll();
        const firstTracker = trackers[0];
        const trackerName = firstTracker.get('name');
        (<any>window).ga(trackerName + '.' + name, data);
    });
}
```

docs: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/accessing-trackers

Comment: Awesome mate! I guess you are using typescript? But not Eslint :) Strange syntax :-) You could use `const` instead of `var` for those and concatenate with ` ${trackerName}.name `

Comment: what are the name and data in this case? I am using GA via GTag Manager

Comment: I named it `name` and `data` as it seems most logical when looking at GA's documentation, but eventually it is just a collection of parameters that you would normally sent to `ga(x,y,z)`. You could also add another function that takes and sends 3 arguments and do something like: `sendGa2('send', "pageview", "shipment");`

Comment: You can get the tracker name with `firstTracker.get('name')`

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/accessing-trackers#getting_data_stored_on_a_tracker