# Analytics Custom Event overridden by GTM? EventLabel always "(not set)"

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have this code triggering on clicking a tab.

```
window.ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'PDP',
  eventAction: 'ChangeTab',
  eventLabel: 'lorem ipsum',
});
```

I have checked Analytics Real time and it shows up but the Event Label is always "(not set)"..

[image]
Is it Google Tag Manager's Click Event that is messing up my event?

[image]
If so how do I work around that? No Tag is fired on the Click.

**EDIT**: Is this the problem that this datalayer variable is defined in GTM?
[image]

Comment: Although you should not have a trailing comma like `eventLabel: 'lorem ipsum',}`, your code worked fine for me and the event label came through. How is this code actually configured in GTM? As a Custom HTML tag? Is your code really `lorem ipsum`, or are you using your GTM variable like `eventLabel: '{{eventLabel}}',`?

Comment: @JoshuaT This code is for Google Analytics tracking directly not for GTM. I've added it to the sites source code. But I think something in our GTM is messing with it removing my data.

the trailing comma is a part of eslint. Doesn't work in IE7 but we don't need to support that :D

Comment: @JoshuaT but great thank you for telling me that it works on a clean GTM! :-) This is what I suspected!

Comment: I have removed this label from GTM now but didn't help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51705995/846348

We're including Analytics via GTM and using "Custom Dimension"/"Trackers" whatever that means.

```
class AnalyticsHelper {
  static DEBUG = false; // requires https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna

  static analyticsSend(data = {}) {
    if (AnalyticsHelper.DEBUG) {
      window.ga_debug = { trace: true };
    }
    window.ga(() => {
      const trackers = window.ga.getAll();
      const firstTracker = trackers[0];
      const trackerName = firstTracker.a.data.values[':name'];
      window.ga(`${trackerName}.send`, data);
    });
  }
}
```